# reinit variable with default constructor plus assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider such code:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    Foo() { a = 17; }
    //void clear() { a = 17; }
};

class Boo {
public:
    void f() {
        foo = Foo();
        //foo.clear();
    }
private:
    Foo foo;
};
```

I compiled it with `gcc` (`-std=c++11`), 
and according to logs in `f` function `foo` was not reintialized with
`foo = Foo();` expression,
but all works fine if I uncomment code with `clear`.

Is code like `foo = Foo();` should be translated to

```
Foo tmp;
memcpy(&foo, &tmp, sizeof(Foo));
```

Or compiler can do some kind of optimization, and after `foo = Foo();` I got garbage in `foo`?

Comment: What? How about posting a minimal working example, please? =)

Comment: The code you've posted should have reinitialized your object. I suspect the error is elsewhere. Can you post a minimal example we can use to replicate your behavior?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6a1043b6576f7d9 Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your actual bug.

Comment: @gsamaras I can not, it reproducible only on hardware with arm and linux with gcc `-O3`. But it question more about `c++` standard, may be I wrong here.

Comment: @templatetypedef It is question about c++ standard, I can only reproduce this bug on specific hardware.

Comment: You have UB somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @user1244932 I'm curios how you're able to compile c++ code using gcc? Or did I get anything wrong here?

Comment: @user1244932 Some of us have arm and linux. (And if you suspect a compiler bug, what version of gcc?) But we have no hope of reproducing or explaining unless you post a *complete* program that demonstrates the bug you're seeing.

Comment: @user0042 I mean `gcc` as collection of compilers, not `c` only compiler.

Comment: @aschepler Actually I can solve bug by myself, the problem for me is understanding may be I use `c++` in wrong way in this particular case.

Comment: @user1244932 Well you put a concrete command line statement?

Comment: @user1244932 Your problem description makes no sense and your code doesn't demonstrate the problem. I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @user1244932 If that's the actual question, please edit the question to say so. But no, there's nothing incorrect about the code you posted except a missing `main`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
foo = Foo();
```

should construct a new instance of class `Foo`.

It creates a new object, allocating memory for it and initializing data member `a` to 17.

---

PS: The error is somewhere else, and since you refused to provide a Minimal Example, we can't tell where.

Comment: Pretend that you didn't see it @melpomene. Like my answer now? :D

Comment: I don't see how it relates to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably use member initializer lists:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    Foo() : a(17) {}
    //void clear() { a = 17; }
};

class Boo {
public:
    Boo() : foo() {}
    void f() {
        foo = Foo();
        //foo.clear();
    }
private:
    Foo foo;
};
```

But beyond that I can't see how the compiler generated copy constructor and assignment operator would leave you with *garbage values* at any point of execution.

Comment: `void f() : foo() {}` is not valid.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for spotting that. Fixed.